# Azure Table Storage as Sink in Data Factory Row Key

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-tablequery

[image]

I want to pass a value for the row key as a parameter just like the partition key. But the UI only gives me an option to use unique identifier or a source column. Actually I need to use this same entity somewhere else. How will I query this entity if the row key is going to be a random value?

Comment: Hi, any updates now ?Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the official [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage#azure-table-as-a-sink-type) , partition key can be set custom value yet row key only could be set column name from source or GUID default value.

[image]

I think it's because of guaranteed uniqueness constraint restrictions. So, if you want to control row key value , you could add row key into your source data.

Hope it helps you.